# Bootstrap collapse - pass value or get DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap I am working with the collapse function to collapse my table sort of [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/whytheday/2Dj7Y/11/).  I am hooking into the [collapse js](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/) with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#demo1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    that = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url:'{{ (path('orders')) }}',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "id": "1"
                },
                async: true,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    console.log(data)
                    $('div#demo1').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data.output + '" />');
                }
            });
            return false;

        });
    </script>
```

How can I either pass a value to that function or get the name of the dom element that passed it (i.e. #demo1)?  I basically need to pass a value to pass as the id value to the ajax POST.

I cannot statically map the values as I'm just generating the rows based off a database return.  The twig is

```
        {% for x in search%}
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo{{ loop.index }}" class="accordion-toggle">
                <th>{{ x.id}}</th>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo{{ loop.index }}">
                        Demo{{ loop.index }} data
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Basically in the above I'm needing access to `x.id` to pass to the bootstrap jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're targeting multiple collapses, you should use class selector instead of the id selector:

```
$(function(){
    $('.accordian-body.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
        ...
    });
});
```

You can get the collapsed DOM element id from **`e.target.id`**.

```
// If using your example:
//   if you click on 1st row you will get:
demo1
//   if you click on 2nd row you will get:
demo2
//   if you click on 3rd row you will get:
demo3
```

If you have more data you need to grab other than the id, you can bind the data using **`data-`** when you construct your HTML, and then jQuery on the target object and go from there:

#### HTML

```
<div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo{{ loop.index }}" 
    data-index="{{ loop.index }}">
    Demo{{ loop.index }} data
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('.accordian-body.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    let $collapsedTarget = $(e.target),
        index = $collapsedTarget.data('index');
});
```

I am not sure if I have answered your question or not, as your question is not clear to me either.

Comment: Ok.  Yeah this is basically the same as what I got down to except it's perhaps better jQuery usage.  Only problem is that index equals '="1"' instead of just "1".  Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: It's not the same IMO, at least I don't use global javascript variable like you did: `id = .....`, which is pretty dangerous. Anyway, you got "=1" from your method or mine?

Comment: Oh - yeah when I said "the same" I meant "as my answer", sorry - yes class is correct, not id.  Anyways, yes from your method I get "=1", from my answer I just get 1.  Is it some kind of type casting?

Comment: No way. If your `{{ loop.index }}` is 1, when the HTML renders, `data-index="{{ loop.index }}"` should give you "1", without "=". I am pretty sure about it, even I can't prove it to you. If you only want the number, try removing the double quote "", like `data-index={{ loop.index }}`.

Comment: Ah nevermind, I made a dumb mistake and did data-index=="" doh. Yes your way gets 1.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a clear question, as the answer depends...

It should be easy, in Javascript you set up a variable outside of the function and declare it so it is global. I.e.

```
<script>let variable;</script>
```

or

```
<script>let variable = 0;</script>
```

or

```
<script>let variable = 'word';</script>
```

Then whether hard code change it or change it via a form entry or select item, as it is global it will be accessible within your function as variable.

You could try something like this:

```
{% for x in search <script>let variable=x;</script> %}
```

Comment: I don't think I can do this.  I updated the post to hopefully explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone wants to see the end code (based off David Liang's answer) for how to do this...

twig:

```
    {% for x in search%}
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo{{ loop.index }}" class="accordion-toggle">
            <th>{{ x.id}}</th>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="hiddenRow">
               <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo{{ loop.index }}" data-index="{{ x.id }}">
                    Loading...
               </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.accordian-body.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    let $collapsedTarget = $(e.target),
        record_id = $collapsedTarget.attr('data-index');
    $.ajax({
        url:'{{ (path('orders')) }}',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "id": record_id.toString()
                },
                async: true,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    console.log('Record ID: ' + record_id);
                    console.log(data)
                    $(e.target).html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data.output + '" />');
                }
            });
            return false;    
        });
</script>
```

and it will replace "Loading..." with whatever you put in the .html() (in my case the img tag).